# Bootstrap Background Image Is Different Across Mobile Browsers

Tags: css, mobile, cross-browser

I'm working on a Bootstrap project using the cover theme. I'm checking this project across all browsers and screen sizes. In some cases, my background photo is great and scrolls as it should. In others, the background photo is just fixed and doesn't scroll. It also crops differently.
Here is my code:

```
html,
body {
height: 100%;
background: url('mccarran_pool.jpg') center center no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size:cover;
}
```

How can I make this cross browser friendly and responsive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should -webkit- and -moz- because in some browsers it doesn't work.
try this:

```
html,
body {
height: 100%;
background: url('mccarran_pool.jpg') center center no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
-webkit-background-size:cover;
-moz-background-size:cover;
background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i've tried this. it's still cropping the image instead of showing the full image. i've also tried

`background-image: 100%;

background-image: 100% 100%:

background-image: auto:

background-image:contain;

background: url('mccarran_pool.jpg');

background-size: cover;`

none of this is working

Comment: Rather, I should say that the whole image is still not showing  on the landing page. you'd have to scroll down to see the bottom instead of viewing the whole thing in the viewport.

Comment: OK.. You want full to be shown.. Try this background-size: 100% 100%; instead of background-size:cover;